# Create .app application bundle from Macports port

Tags: applications, macports

Is it possible to create an [Mac OS X .app application bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(OS_X)#OS_X_application_bundles) from a Macports port without having to modify the compilation process?

The goal is a portable .app folder and not a .pkg that messes up /opt/ or /usr/ folder structures and requires root rights to install.

I imagine this might be possible by using scripts that simulate an environment in which the application exists as it was originally placed in by Macports but also think the resulting .app might not be portable because of required external libraries that can't be legally included.

Is it possible? How would one go about this?

I was able to find instructions for [PyQt](https://ar.al/1675/), [Octave](http://wiki.octave.org/Create_a_MacOS_X_App_Bundle_Using_MacPorts) and [Go](https://github.com/agl/pond/blob/master/client/build-osx-bundle.sh) but they are specific to specific libraries or programming languages.